# vertical and horizontal alignment of image canceling

Tags: html, css, alignment

```css
.floral-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    }
```

```html
<div id="heading">

    <div id="colD"><p><img class="floral-icon" src="_images/pg_p_lewis_icon.png" alt="floral icon" width="32" height="32"></p></div>
    <div id="colE"><p>Lewis</p></div>
    <div id="colF"><p><img class="floral-icon" src="_images/pg_p_lewis_icon.png" alt="floral icon" width="32" height="32"></p></div>    
    </div>
```

I am trying to align an icon on both sides of a single word heading.  I want it to align in the middle vertically and on the right side to the left of the heading and on the left side to the right of the heading, so that the icon abuts up to the heading on either side.  When I leave off the float property to align it left or right, the icon lines up correct vertically.  When I add the float the icon jumps up to the top and is not aligning correctly in the vertical position.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

forget about float and vertical align, it's an old tricks. try the flex, it's a new one.

put a wrapper before your icons and set display flex.

this is some simple example from me, you should improve it by your self

```css
.wrap{
width:100%;
height:250px;
background:yellow;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:flex-end;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.icons{
width:50px;
height:50px;}

.icons img{
width:100%;}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <div class='icons'><img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-metallic-orbs-icons-natural-wonders/050386-blue-metallic-orb-icon-natural-wonders-flower9.png"></div>
  <div class='icons'><img src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/blue-metallic-orbs-icons-natural-wonders/050386-blue-metallic-orb-icon-natural-wonders-flower9.png"></div>
</div>
```

you can find it more in this link [css Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

wish, it would help you out. ask me more, if you still don't get it.

Comment: Thanks.  It's working pretty well except the 2 icons and the single word heading in between them are all the way on the right hand side of the page, even though I put align-items: center in the .wrap div.  I would post my code but when I hit enter to make a break between lines the message gets posted.  I can't seem to get the hang of how to post your code on this site.

Comment: @BartonLewis just like i said, you should improve it by yourself. edit your code above and your question as well, and let me see what was the problem. it's hard to see things with words